tkinter button image inside a function not working - python
I've been trying to get this to work with no luck so far. I simplified the code to only the relevant pieces. I can display an image button in the main class, but inside a function I cannot get the button to dislpay correctly. I understand the concept of garbage collecting, so I've tried using nothing, 'self.' and 'new_window' as prefix, as well as multiple combinations thereof, but with no luck. What am I doing wrong?
from tkinter import *

class tkinterApp(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        def some_other_function():
            pass

        def open_new_window():
            new_window = Tk()

            new_window.image = PhotoImage(file='image.png')
            btn2 = Button(new_window, image=new_window.image, command=some_other_function)
            btn2.pack()

        self.image = PhotoImage(file='image.png')
        btn1 = Button(self, image=self.image, command=open_new_window)
        btn1.pack()

tkinterApp().mainloop()


It is because you create multiple instances of Tk().  Use Toplevel() inside open_new_window().

omg i was looking in the wrong place for a solution. Thanks!!!

When creating photoimages with multiple windows, specify the master to prevent headaches
